# Why cant I execute the bulk of .sql file without using exit at the end of sql file through java

Tags: java, oracle10g

I am trying to execute .sql file from java. It runs successfully when I put exit at the end of the .sql file. Is there any possibility to run without giving exit in .sql?

Java code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {

  private static String script_location = "";
  private static String file_extension = ".sql";
  private static ProcessBuilder processBuilder =null;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      //D:/Tset is the folder that contains the.sql files
      File file = new File("D:/Tset");
      File [] list_files= file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File f) {
          if (f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(file_extension))
          return true;

          return false;
        }
      });
      for (int i = 0; i&lt;list_files.length;i++){
        script_location = "@" + list_files[i].getAbsolutePath();
        //ORACLE
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder
        ("sqlplus","user56/password",  script_location); //ORACLE
        //script_location = "-i" + list_files[i].getAbsolutePath();
        //  processBuilder =
        new ProcessBuilder("sqlplus",
        "-Udeep-Pdumbhead-Spc-de-deep\\sqlexpress-de_com",script_location);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader in =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String currentLine = null;
        while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(" "  + currentLine);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Oracle script file:

**createtable.sql**

```
createtable.sql
create table t1(empname varchar2(20),address varchar2(20))
/
create table t2(name varchar2(20),lname varchar2(20))
/
exit;
```

**insertvalue.sql**

```
insert into t1 values('aaaaa','chennai')
/
insert into t2 values('bbbbb','ddddd')
/
exit;
```

If I don't put an exit at last it simply runs the first file only. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: the exit is for the sqlplus program, why do you want to remove it ? and why do you run sqlplus from java and not use JDBC ?

Comment: Thank u for ur reply.if i use jdbc then it will execute line by line or it needs some terminator for each  and every query for that i want to use split or delimiters.its not fine for my application.i want to execute bulk of sql statements.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you run the command `sqlplus` in a loop so you must end every command (using exit to exit sqlplus).
If you want to call many scripts on the same sqlplus instance then maybe you can create "on the fly" a script that has commands such as:
**onTheFlyAcript.sql**

```
@createtable.sql <your params>
@insertvalue.sql <your params>
exit;
```

So basically you can do something like:

```
try {
   Printwriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("D:/Test/onTheFlyScript.sql"));
   for (int i = 0; i&lt;list_files.length;i++){
        script_location = "@" + list_files[i].getAbsolutePath();
        out.println("START script_location");
   }              
   out.close();
} catch (IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
// note that this command is not in the loop, it's just for running the new script you've created
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder
        ("sqlplus","user56/password",  "D:/Test/onTheFlyAcript.sql");
```

This will probably have to be debuged, but the idea is that instead of executing all your scripts one by one with sqlplus, you create a new script that contains the calls to all your scripts.
Now you can remove the `exit` sqlplus command from all your scripts since you don't need to exit sqlplus (only in onTheFlyScript.sql)

Comment: Thank you.actually am in need to execute 3 .sql files. the first file for table creation its nearly 24 tables.2nd file for inserting values to the table nearly wan to insert 375 values.3rd file for stored procedure it has 15 procedures.

Comment: those 3 files are saved under D:/script folder(for ex).In my java pgm simply i gave tat file path(D:/script).for tat i have used processbuilder its taking by alphabetic order so create.sql then insert.sql then procedure.sql.if i give exit at the end of the create.sql then only the control will be transferred to next file ie insert.sql.otherwise its simply running create.sql file alone.

Comment: other two files are not running.thats my prob.i wan to run without using exit at the end of the .sql file.can u reply plz

Comment: If you do it the way suggested, you don't need `exit` in the files only in file that calls them (the file you build on the fly in your java code) that's because you don't need to exit sqlplus program. the `@` can be replaced with the sqlplus command `START` - you start within the same sqlplus instance all the calls to the other files

Comment: I added it in the answer. I didn't try to run the code but I hope it will help you understand my idea...